# What was the first anime to be legally streamed online by its original broadcasters?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

I remember *NieA_7* being streamed legally by the broadcaster's a week after the episode was released and this was like back in 2000ish. But, I am not sure if there were any other anime series before this that was also legally streamed online by their original broadcasters.

What was the first anime to be legally streamed online by it's original broadcasters?

Comment: For those who don't know about *NieA_7*, could you explain a little bit how the broadcast worked? I assume this is in Japan since you mentioned year 2000, or did you mean the English one in 2007? Where was it streamed online?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I remember "Druaga no Tou: The Aegis of Uruk" (2008) was the first anime to release as a legal stream on the Internet both in Japan and internationally with subtitles on the same date.

The way I remember, it was a novelty and mostly people shrugged without paying attention. The next thing I heard about the responsible studio (Gonzo) was that they filed for bankruptcy.